# Why PHP is allocating too much memory than the loaded image?

Tags: php, gd

I executed the following PHP code:

```
$a = memory_get_usage();
$b = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $a.' bytes ('.($a/1024/1024).' MB), '.$b.' bytes ('.($b/1024/1024).' MB)<br>';

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('image.jpg');

$a = memory_get_usage();
$b = memory_get_usage(true);
echo $a.' bytes ('.($a/1024/1024).' MB), '.$b.' bytes ('.($b/1024/1024).' MB)';
```

The size of the image is `8.8 MB` with resolution `8185 x 5787`.

The output was as following:

```
396168 bytes (0.37781524658203 MB), 2097152 bytes (2 MB)
190081952 bytes (181.27627563477 MB), 127926272 bytes (122 MB)
```

As can be seen, before loading the image, PHP/script's memory usage was only `0.3778.. MB` (or maximum `2 MB`) but after loading the image of `8.8 MB`, the memory usage increased to `181 MB` (`181 / 8.8 = 20.57` times than the image)!

Why PHP is using too much memory than the loaded image? It is understandable to use 2 to 5 times, but 20.57 times doesn't seems too much?

---

And another thing, this is what documentation of PHP `memory_get_usage([ bool $real_usage = FALSE ] ) : int` is saying about it's parameter:

> If not set or FALSE only the used memory is reported. Set this to TRUE to get total memory allocated from system, including unused pages.

I find it confusing. In the first line of output, the **used memory** is `0.3778 MB` while **total memory allocated from system** is `2 MB`, which seems fine. But in the second line of output, **used memory** is `181 MB` while **total memory allocated from system** is `122 MB`. How can total memory be less than the used memory?

Comment: You can try ImageMagick instead of GD.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thanks. I tried Imagick (ImageMagick) with changing the 5th line of the code to `$img = new Imagick('image.jpg');` and the out is showing: **392128 bytes (0.37396240234375 MB), 2097152 bytes (2 MB)** and **392192 bytes (0.3740234375 MB), 2097152 bytes (2 MB)** for the same 8.8 MB image! Now PHP is not even occupying memory equivalent to the image, that's really [image] magic! :-D